# Alternatives to way old HTML iframes

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, web-component, shadow-dom

We have been using HTML `<iframe>` tags since a while as we need separate scope, especially Javascript scrips/functions/variables and CSS styles which need to be bound to a sandbox context which is provided by iframes. Because in our application, with in a document there can be multiple sub-documents/portlets which should be processed in their own sandbox context.

For the obvious reasons, **iframes** eat up memory overtime (especially in IE) - so we want to replace them with the latest technologies as the web has evolved far better now. Have been hearing about https://www.webcomponents.org/ but not sure if it supports Javascript scoping like CSS styles.

This question might have been posted before on stackoverflow but wanted to hear latest perspective on this now.

Appreciate your time and attention.

Comment: _"not sure if it supports Javascript scoping like CSS styles."_ How is CSS related to JavaScript scope? Not certain what question is?

Comment: Google maps and Youtube embeds still use iframes. I believe that if anything works better than iframes for the intended purpose then Google would be the first to use it on their products.

Comment: @guest271314, Read that css styles defined in the webcomponent template are bound to that template and don't bleed-in or out (like firefox scope attribute). Similarly wanted to know if that is the case even with Javascript variable/functions ?

Comment: What do you mean by "bleed-in or out"?

Comment: If by "bleed-in or out" you mean a css style sheet only applies to a single component of your site, you could do this by giving that components container HTMLtag a class to reference it through like `component-1` or `component-header`. For the JavaScript, is there any reason why old fashioned [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Emulating_private_methods_with_closures) aren't enough?

Comment: Correct @EmilS.Jørgensen, currently we are mimicking the sandbox via closures to some extent but there are some global variables which are being returned in server response which doesn't work without iframes as they will be overridden for subsequent requests. So looking for some out-of-box solution.

Comment: To "scope" JS you should create a custom element. Note that Shadow DOM is not and will never be supported by IE.

Comment: I think what the poster means with JavaScript scoping is that JavaScript DOM operations be limited to a certain container like with scoped CSS rather than entire HTML document. I.e. prevent `document.getElementById()` from searching the entire DOM, and only search children of a container.